# Can FlexNativeMenu with a e4x XML dataProvider have <> characters in its attributes?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

As the question states, I get `XML parser failure: Unterminated attribute` whenever I try to use the angle brackets as part of a value of one of my attributes.  For example all cause XML errors:

```
<menuitem label="<em>"/>
<menuitem label="&lt;em&gt;"/>
<menuitem label="&#60;em&#62;"/>
```

Is there a way to include angle brackets in these menu items when using it with a FlexNativeMenu in Flex 4?

Comment: I would have suggested what the second option you had listed.  What error are you getting?  Is it compile time or runtime?

Comment: Its runtime and its the error I listed in the first sentence of my post.

Comment: And I was just reading something about read comprehension; I guess I failed that test.

Comment: Can you post the whole error?  which line does it affect?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try setting the label in ActionScript:

```
menuItem.label = '&lt;em&gt;';
```

If you're intent on doing this in MXML; I would try an approach like this, using the cdata declaration to escape things:

```
<Menuitem>
 <label><![CDATA[<em>]]></label>
</Menuitem>
```

Comment: Yes, I am intent on keeping the definition of my menu in the MXML.  Unfortunately, your MXML solution doesn't work.  The label field apparently must be an attribute, not a child element.

Comment: @Tony Lukasavage It's hard to tell exactly what is going on without seeing any more code than what you've shown.  I assume that MenuItem refers to the MenuItem class.  In which case, there is no reason you can't define 'label' as a child in MXML.  It's just a different syntax to do the same thing and should work.  You said it "didn't work but didn't say why.  Did you a compile error?  If so, what was it?